# How can I take input from either stdin or a file if I cannot seek stdin?

Tags: io, rust, traits, downcast

I am porting some Python to Rust as a learning exercise and need to take input from either a file or stdin. I keep a handle to my input in a struct so I thought I'd just make a `Box<io::Read>` but I ran into a situation where I need to seek on the input, and `seek` isn't part of the `Read` trait. I know you can't seek in pipes, so I'm going ahead and assuming for now that this method only gets called when the input is a file, but my problem is that I can't check that and downcast in Rust.

I know that I could use an enum for the two input types, but it seems like there should be a more elegant way to do this. And that's my question, how do you do this and not make a mess?

Is it possible to wrap stdin or a file in the same sort of buffer so I could just use that type and not worry about the type of IO?

Comment: What operations do you need to `seek` the input? If you really need an arbitrary `seek` the only hope is read the whole stdin into a `Cursor<Vec<u8>>`.

Comment: You obviously don't **need** to seek if you can handle reading from stdin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know, you said you wanted something more elegant and without enums, but I think the enum-solution *is* fairly elegant. So here is one attempt:

```
use std::fs;
use std::io::{self, Read, Seek, SeekFrom};

enum Input {
    File(fs::File),
    Stdin(io::Stdin),
}

impl Read for Input {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        match *self {
            Input::File(ref mut file) => file.read(buf),
            Input::Stdin(ref mut stdin) => stdin.read(buf),
        }
    }
}

impl Seek for Input {
    fn seek(&mut self, pos: SeekFrom) -> io::Result<u64> {
        match *self {
            Input::File(ref mut file) => file.seek(pos),
            Input::Stdin(_) => {
                Err(io::Error::new(
                    io::ErrorKind::Other, 
                    "not supported by stdin-input",
                ))
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Put code like that in some sub module of yours and don't worry about it too much  anymore. You can use an object of type `Input` just like you would use a `File`: you have to handle seek errors anyway, so handling the inability to seek by stdin should be super easy. An example:

```
let arg = std::env::args().nth(1).unwrap();
let mut input = if arg == "--" {
    Input::Stdin(io::stdin())
} else {
    Input::File(fs::File::open(&arg).expect("I should handle that.."))
};

let mut v = Vec::new();
let _idc = input.read_to_end(&mut v);

match input.seek(SeekFrom::End(0)) {
    Err(_) => println!("oh noes :("),
    Ok(bytes) => println!("yeah, input is {} long", bytes),
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to wrap stdin or a file in the same sort of buffer so I could just use that type and not worry about the type of io?

That's exactly what the trait `Read` does. It seems that what you want is an abstraction (trait) for `Stdin` and `File` that has optional support for `seek` and allows to query about this support. In the following code,  `OptionalSeekRead` trait is used to fulfill this intend:

```
use std::io::{Read, Seek, SeekFrom, Stdin};
use std::fs::File;

// define a trait alias
pub trait SeekRead: Seek + Read {}

impl<T: Seek + Read> SeekRead for T {}

pub trait OptionSeekRead: Read {
    fn get_seek_read(&mut self) -> Option<&mut SeekRead>;
}

impl OptionSeekRead for File {
    fn get_seek_read(&mut self) -> Option<&mut SeekRead> {
        Some(self)
    }
}

impl OptionSeekRead for Stdin {
    fn get_seek_read(&mut self) -> Option<&mut SeekRead> {
        None
    }
}

struct Handle {
    read: Box<OptionSeekRead>,
}

impl Handle {
    fn f(&mut self) {
        if let Some(h) = self.read.get_seek_read() {
            // h is Seek + Read
            h.seek(SeekFrom::Start(42));
        } else {
            // without Seek
        }
    }
}
```