# Handling TcpStream or SslStream idiomatically

Tags: rust

I'm working on a project that can use either `TcpStream`s or `SslStream`s, depending on what the user configured. I have a few simple methods such as `send_cmd(stream)` and `recv_msg(stream)` which operates on these streams.

Would it be more idiomatic to create an enum that could be either `TcpStream` or `SslStream` and pass that to these methods? Or would it be better to do something with traits, such as requiring the stream argument to these methods implement the `Read` and `Write` traits?

My thought is that the enum solution would be better, as it explicitly says what kind of data we expect to be handling instead of allowing for anything that implements `Read` or `Write`, such as files. On the flip side though, it would require a match on all of these methods before using the stream. Thoughts?

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/37223741/5189607.

Comment: What benefit does your code (or users of your code) gain by limiting to only two concrete types?

Comment: @Shepmaster: It's an API implementation to a service only available over tcp.

Comment: @malbarbo: That is hugely helpful, thanks! :)

Comment: That doesn't provide a benefit to limiting the types, it's just an implementation detail. What about dependency injection during testing or adding a logging layer for debugging or a compression layer or a ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a solution for this built into the openssl library: [`openssl::ssl::MaybeSslStream`](https://doc.servo.org/openssl/ssl/enum.MaybeSslStream.html).